# centos 7 zip directory

Tags: command-line, centos7

how to undo gzip command in centos?

```
sudo gzip -r plugins
```

if I try `sudo gunzip -r plugins` it give me an error `not in gzip format`

what I want  to do is zip the directory.

Comment: What do you mean by undo? Do you want to unzip?

Comment: gunzip  all the files in the directory and sub directories

Comment: If `gzip` created `plugins.gz`, you have to call `gunzip plugins.gz`. Just look how your archive is named (use `ls`).

Comment: found the solution below

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two questions

1. How do I undo what I did?
2. How do I zip a directory

Have you even looked at `man gzip` or `gzip --help`?

Answers

1. `find plugins -type f -name "*gz" | xargs gunzip`
2. `tar -zcvf plugins.tar.gz plugins`

   - 2b. I suspect that your level of linux experience is low so you'd probably be more comfortable using `zip`. (Remember to do a `zip --help` or `man zip` before coming for more advice.)

Explanation. `gzip` only zips up *one file*. If you want to do a bunch of files, you have to smush them up into one file first (using `tar`) and then compress that using `gzip`.

What you did was recursively gzip up each *individual* file in `plugins/`.

Answer (score 0):

```
tar -zcvf archive.tar.gz directory/
```

check this answers https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/93158 https://askubuntu.com/a/553197 & https://www.centos.org/docs/2/rhl-gsg-en-7.2/s1-zip-tar.html

Answer (score 0):

sudo find . -name "*.gz" -exec gunzip {} \;